# Explorer.exe CPU Usage Increases with Non-Explorer Processes?

Tags: windows, cpu, cpu-usage, explorer

I have a program which runs in windows explorer. Ordinarily, if no other programs are running, it will use 2-3% CPU (Hence explorer.exe will show 2-3% in the resource monitor). When my program is not running and another program that does not increase explorer.exe CPU usage is running (say for example FireFox), explorer.exe CPU usage will be negligible.

However when my program and another program, like that described above, are running simultaneously, explorer.exe will increase to 8-10% CPU usage.

I've noticed this same thing happen with other programs that operate in windows explorer.

Is anyone aware of why this is occurring? Is it something inherent in Windows or are there other programs which may cause this?

P.S This has nothing to do with Internet Explorer (iexplorer.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of task-switching (and maybe additionally paging). If there is only one prgram that needs a lot of CPU-time and/or memory-accesses it will be given many CPU-time-slices and thus will be able to run un-interrupted for a "long" time. On the other hand if multiple processes need a lot of CPU-time, Windows will task-switch frequently between them and thus introduce **additional** overhead (because it needs to store/load process-state on every task-switch). If you have 2 CPUs this is less problematic but still measurable because background-processes also need attention albeit less frequent.

See here for more information:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch

Insert Sleep(10) calls into your program; your program should get longer but less-frequent time-slices:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response! The only potential reason I can imagine this not being the cause is that the CPU usage of the other program that does not rely on explorer.exe does not increase? On the other hand if I run multiple programs that are not dependant on explorer.exe the CPU usage of those programs does not increase greatly over their individual usage like in the above scenario.

Comment: Yes, that is interesting. It may be that indeed paging occurs and the paging cost is carried by explorer.exe. Did you try the Sleep(10)?

Comment: I've tried adding Sleep(10) calls previously though it makes little difference. I am not sure that there is a way to actually decrease this side-effect but your answer does cover the bases as to why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

explorer subscribes to file-system events in order to update its display when files change size, date, new files created, etc.

If another process is touching a lot of files, it could increase the work explorer has to do, and therefore explorer's CPU utilization.